# SQL Left Join via foreign keys, how to avoid duplicate columns?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have numerous tables I join with a primary key field. I can query with the below to get the results I need.

```
Select *
from orders
Left Join serviceorders on orders.contractLineID = serviceorders.lineID
Left Join all_orders on orders.OrderNum = all_orders.ordernum
Left Join invoices on orders.OrderNum = invoices.OrderNum
Left Join schedule on orders.OrderNum = schedule.Ordernum;
```

But when I try to create a view from this, I face duplicate columns, as each table I'm joining has the ordernum in it.

I know I shouldn't use * to select everything, but I don't know the syntax for selecting columns from multiple tables?

Is it just:

```
SELECT orders.column1, orders.column2 schedule.column1, schedule.column 2, invoice.column1, invoice.column2

FROM orders, schedule, invoice
```

I've also seen you can use the USING command, but the syntax for that is unclear. I'm not sure if that would be the better option as it's just the one column that's being repeated across all tables.

Comment: If you want specific columns only, do not use `SELECT *` specifiy the columns. This is done by declaring the [tablename].[column] (with comma separation between each)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, learn to use aliases.  Second, you should list all the columns:

```
Select o.col1, o.col2, so.col3,  -- list columns you want explicitly
       ao.col3 as ao_col3        -- if you still have duplicates, assign new names
from orders o left join
     serviceorders so
     on o.contractLineID = so.lineID left join
     all_orders ao
     on o.OrderNum = ao.ordernum left join
     invoices i
     on o.OrderNum = i.OrderNum left join
     schedule s
     on o.OrderNum = s.Ordernum;
```

Comment: I've managed to get it to work doing this. I don't suppose there's an easy way to select everything but certain columns?

Comment: @PeterCollins . . . Not in MySQL.  Google's BigQuery supports an `EXCEPT` clause which does exactly that.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the syntax:

```
SELECT TableA.id AS tableA_id, -- Or anything you want to name it after 'AS'
       TableB.id AS tableB_id
  FROM TableA
 INNER
  JOIN TableB
    ON TableA.key = TableB.key
```

This is if you need the view to have both ids, with a distinct name. Better yet only select the columns you want.